# Unity build for hololens leaves empty folder

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I have created a very simple demo in Unity (editor version 2020.3.26f1) by just importing the HandInteractionExamples and would like to build it for Hololens. I am encountering two problems:

1. I get a gazillion "please remove the CanvasRenderer component from ...", which I cannot possibly remove manually, because there are too many. They are only warnings, though.
2. Among these many warnings I get one error, saying that it can't move some build files into the folder that I specified because "access denied". How can that be? I restarted my machine to make sure nothing has a handle on that folder. Still, access is denied for some reason. The build folder resides in the project folder and is called "UWP".

Comment: The `please remove the CanvasRenderer component from...` are all coming from `TextMeshPro`. Previously they all needed that `CanvasRenderer` but in an update of the TMP package it became redundant and is no longer needed/desired on TextMeshPro components .. but as said it's a warning and shouldn't cause build time issues .. you could wrote an editor script for removing it everywhere but that's a bit more complex ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the denied access to the folder. Due to a malware problem, I had a software called Spyhunter 5 installed. When I turn that off, the problem goes away.